# Why Android restarts the app when returning from Dialer ? (or any other service)

Tags: android, resources, restart, tel

We have a page that has a links to a tel number (a href="tel:5551234567"), when the user touches the link, it opens up the dialer. After the user end the call, and hit back, instead of just returning the browser, you can see that the browser is being restarted, thus the page is reloading. Why this happens ?

You can easy load this URL (http://goo.gl/QKbrC9) in your device and touch the Call (555) link.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It is default behaviour for Android.

When the call is taking place you have moved outside the browser app and into a new one. The dialer app has no idea about the browser, so when back is pressed the Android OS takes over and starts the browser app. This starts a new browser, whereas, if the dialer *knew* about the browser, it could flag it to reorder to front.

That being said, it is possible to make an app counter this with somthing like:

```
    private class EndCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    private final String LOG_TAG = "EndCallListener";

    private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
            // finish();
        }
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            // wait for phone to go offhook (probably set a boolean flag) so
            // you know your app initiated the call.
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");
            isPhoneCalling = true;
        }
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {

                // run when class initial and phone call ended,
                // need detect flag from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");

                if (isPhoneCalling) {

                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "restart app");

                    // restart app
                    Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                                    getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                    // i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                    startActivity(i);

                    isPhoneCalling = false;
                }


        }
    }
```

But evidently the browser has no obvious reason to handle this specifically.

Comment: Is this behavior the same if the dialer is called from any app ? On dialer return the calling app restarts ?

Comment: No. If the app is designed to handle phone calls, as described above (which reorders the app activity to front instead of creating a new one), or as a single running instance (meaning there can only be one of this activity running), then returning from a phonecall will not result in a new activity being created in place of the original before the call. Games, for instance, often is designed as the latter so that you can simply resume the game after ending a call.

Comment: What devices have you tested? Just went ahead and actually tried making the call from you site to test behaviour and my phone (Samsung S2 CyanogenMod 10.1 Android 4.2.2) and it did not reload the page. Perhaps with more recent versions Android has become more clever handling these situations, with fragments and all.. My discussion was based on my knowledge on default behaviour and experience with making phonecalls from within my app. I used it for automatic redirecting the number to another phone and had to do the above code to get back to my app.

Comment: I tried on my phone Samsung Galaxy S3. I read somewhere that Android terminate process when resource is needed. It sounded like if the Dialer needs resources, the browser in this case is shut down, upon return it start all over. I have noticed this happens (browser restart) only sometimes. Anyway, I tried to use the browser to formulate this question for a more general question. My real issue is when a Worklight App (actually Android app) restarts upon return from dialer. Looks like it is not related to Worklight at all, it sounds to me much more on the OS behavior